# add PHP variable in SQL WHERE

Tags: php, sql

on my first UPDATE statement, im trying to have my WHERE value contain the variable $couponCode but it does not work as of now. This is so that the correct row updates depending on what the input is. any help would be appreciated.

```
if ($couponCode == $coupons_db3['coupon_code']){
   echo $couponCode;
   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE promocode_3 SET used = 1 WHERE coupon_code ='.$couponCode);
   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE usr_customer_profile SET packageid = 3 WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid');
   $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   break;
 }
```

Comment: Prepare, bind (ie `WHERE coupon_code = :couponCode`) and execute your first query in the same way you are doing for your second query

Comment: id like to see an example of that, i already turned the line into: "$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE promocode_3 SET used = 1 WHERE coupon_code = :couponCode);"

Comment: And are you then binding `$couponCode`? How about executing that prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the `couponCode` as well.

```
if ($couponCode == $coupons_db3['coupon_code']){
       echo $couponCode;
       $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE promocode_3 SET used = 1 WHERE coupon_code =:couponCode');
       $stmt->bindValue(':couponCode', $couponCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute();

       $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE usr_customer_profile SET packageid = 3 WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid');
       $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->execute();
       break;
     }
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume `$couponCode` is an integer. I mean, it might be but OP hasn't confirmed so I'd just use the default bind type for now

Comment: Let him set that :) We are just helping him to solve his coding problems

Comment: is because the single quotation was not closed in the UPDATE or is it something else?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention its a string varchar

Comment: i see that i had to make sure the PARAM and both need their separate execute(). thanks this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

**Please ignore..  @Bira's answer is more accurate**

Try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE promocode_3 SET used = 1 WHERE coupon_code ='".$couponCode."'");
```

you missed the quote in coupon code value.
P.S. I don't know which database you are using. Please mention that next time. :)

This should work but it's not an ideal case for a prepared statement because in case of prepared statements you should give parameters only at the time of execution.

"prepare" should only compile an sql statement and parameters should be passed later on.